# different layout for different gridview in the tabslayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a tablayout. In the first tab there is a gridview layout. On the last tab there is a button. On click of the button another tablayout screen is displayed. This tabbed screen in turn contains another gridview.

My problem is that the inner gridview layout is not loaded, instead even in the inner screens the homescreen gridview is visible. There is no error in the logcat.

Any ideas please?

Thanks,

Comment: Please add a screenshot. I cannot imagine what you mean. Please also add an image what you expect.